# Is it safe to use public const with strings?

Tags: c#, constants

I have heard that it is a bad idea to do something like:

```
public const double Pi = 3;
```

because later when I realise I need to change it to `3.14`, other assembillies will not be able to see the change until they are recompiled too.  Therefore `readonly` would be a better choice.

Does the same apply to strings?  For example with

```
public const string Name = "Buh";
```

it is only the reference that is constant, right?  Or does the compiler do something clever here?

**Is the the string literal, "Buh" inlined into other assemblies? Or is only the reference to "Buh" inlined?**

Comment: Is that right? When an assembly is compiled against another, the const values are inlined? Well I never...

Comment: @spender - Indeed they are. Take a look at Eric Lipperts blog where he talks about compiler optimizations, and then constant folding among others. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx

Comment: I suppose if you stick to only exposing methods and properties, then this is a non-problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the compiler, before the IL is generated, will replace all constants with the actual value of the constant, so it does not matter what type it is. If it's a string, double, int or whatever, the assemblies that use the const will continue to use the old value untill they are recompiled, since the compiled IL has no knowledge of any constant ever existing. It just know about the value itself, just like if you had hardcoded it directly.

readonly on the other hand is evaluated like other non-readonly fields, and therefore changes will be seen by other assemblies regardless of the type of the readonly field.

Comment: I quess what I'm thinking is that you could keep the value of `Name` (which is the reference) the same, but change the string literal which it points to.

Comment: @Buh Buh: Please check the links. After compilation, there will be no constant with the name `Name`. Everywhere it has been used will be the value of it.

Comment: Right that is precisly what is confusing me. The value of Name is not "Buh". The value of name is a reference pointing to "Buh". If the value is constant, the reference is constant, then it is still pointing to my origonal "Buh" object?

Comment: @Buh Buh - Think of it like this: The first thing the compiler does is to replace all occurrences of **Name** with **"Buh"**, then remove the entire `const Name...` line altogether. So there is no Name reference poiting to **"Buh"** at all. It's just the same as if you didn't write the const **Name** at all, and just types in **"Buh"** wherever you wanted the value of **Name**. It should actually be quite easy to grasp if you think about it :)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - I have read the links, but I'm not don't see anything there which really answers my question.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen - I get the idea, you're right it's easy. I'm just being thown off by the word value. The value is a reference. I havn't seen any documentation to say that the object itself is inlined too. Maybe I'm just being too pedantic.

Comment: To take it one step further... it seems making a reference type constant will actually CHANGE its value in other assembilies, as it is now pointing to a copy.

Comment: Reference type constant? A const member must evaluate to a compile-time constant. You can write `const int MyValue = 5;`, but you can't write `const MyClass MyValue = new MyClass();`. What do you mean when you say reference type constant?

Comment: I mean `const string Name = "Buh";`. Where string is the reference type.

Comment: string is actually a special case here. For reference type consts the only values they can have is either a string literal or null. No other values are possible. So don't trick yourself into thinking that the const is a actual member with a value that anyone can point to. Same as for value type const, the literal string is just copied to all the places the const is used in code at compilation. Just as if you had put the literal string in place of the const throughout your code, and *just* as for a value type const.

Comment: Well yes, it's a special case, but then it's always a special case. You can't have `const MyStruct M = new MyStruct()` either.  I think I'm happy with it all now though, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2004/01/27/63416.aspx

`const` is compile-time, so you're right: use `readonly` if it might change in the future!

Comment: i got the alert answer posted but didn't check those, anyways voted to delete my post

Answer (score 1):

strings are immutable, so it is the same as for double.

Comment: If I now change "Buh" to "Frank" as my compile time, what happens to the existing assembilies?  Are their references now pointing to "Frank" or do they have some copy of "Buh" or are they just pointing to some lost bit of memory?

Comment: As with the double, the assemblies that where compiled when your constant had the value "Buh", will still have the value "Buh", because the value of the constant is inlined into these assemblies, i.e. when those assemblies access that constant, they are not leaving their own code and will *not* access the assembly the constant was defined in.

Comment: I just want to check, because the value of Name is a reference.  I'm not sure if it inlines the string object itself.  I quess you're saying it does.

Comment: It does and it does so with every object, regardless of whether it is a reference type or a value type. Please check the links provided by others.

Comment: Just to go back to your answer... could you explain why it makes any difference if string is immutabable or not? I don't follow your logic.